# Problem with adding a new document in Firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firestore:
**Collection**(Models) -> **Document**(Fan) -> **Collection**(Assets)

And I want to add a new document to the collection(Assets)

Here's the HTML code:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="asset_id" />
 <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
const assets = firestore.collection("Models").doc("Fan").collection("Assets");

document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
var asset_id = document.getElementById("asset_id").value;
 addAsset(asset_id);
});

const addAsset = asset => {
    assets.add({asset_type: asset});
};
```

but the code doesn't work and nothing is added to the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning the `submit` type to your button, your form is submitted before the Firebase method is triggered.

Changing the type to `button`, as follows, should do the trick:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="asset_id" />
 <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

See the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) for more detail.